# Not quite getting the expected results when using filter

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Still very new to R, or any programming, presenting some health outcome data to the department and thought I would try writing something that will let me select which subset of data to display.  Done some self directed reading and tried the following (please see below).
The problem I have is when I select all 4 "Surgical Approaches", the results I get is not what I expect.  For example, the mean LOS for July 2019 should be lower than what I see here.

As I said, very new to this, please assume I know nothing when answering this question.

```
# User Interface

ui <-basicPage(
  sliderInput("year", "Select Year:", animate = T,
              min = 2016, max = 2019, value = 2016, sep = ""),

  checkboxGroupInput("approach", "Surgical Approach", c("Laparoscopic", "Lap-assisted", "Converted to open", "Open"),
                     selected = c("Laparoscopic", "Lap-assisted", "Converted to open", "Open")),

plotOutput(outputId = "LOS_plot"),

  plotOutput(outputId = "All3_plot")
)

# Server

server <- function(input, output){

  output$LOS_plot <- renderPlot({

    ERAS %>% filter(Sx_Approach == input$approach) %>% 
      arrange(year_m) %>% 
      mutate(DoSdate = ymd(year_m), yearDoS = year(DoSdate), monthDoS = month(DoSdate)) %>% 
      filter(yearDoS == input$year) %>%
      group_by(year_m) %>% mutate(mean_LOS = mean(Postop_LOS)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = monthDoS, y = mean_LOS)) + geom_line(colour = "black", size = 1.5) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 12), breaks = c(1:12)) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 30), minor_breaks = 1) +
      theme(aspect.ratio = 0.4) + xlab("Month") + ylab("Days") + ggtitle("Mean Length of Stay over Time")

  })
  output$All3_plot <- renderPlot({

    ERAS %>% filter(Sx_Approach == input$approach) %>%
      arrange(year_m) %>% 
      mutate(DoSdate = ymd(year_m), yearDoS = year(DoSdate), monthDoS = month(DoSdate)) %>% 
      filter(yearDoS == input$year) %>%
      group_by(year_m) %>% mutate(mean_All3 = mean(All_3 == T, na.rm = T)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = monthDoS, y = mean_All3)) + geom_line(colour = "#5391c6", size = 1.5) + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 12), breaks = c(1:12)) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0, 1)) +
      theme(aspect.ratio = 0.4) + xlab("Month") + ylab("Percentage") + ggtitle("Patients Achieving All Three ERAS Goals")

  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using 'filter', try using 'subset' to select just the portion of your data frame with your sliderInput and checkboxGroupInput.  Without knowing the data structure you're using, it would look something like this:

```
ERAS <-  subset(Sx_Approach, (year==input$year & approach==input$approach))
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I played around with the code since posting the question and found that instead of `filter(Sx_Approach == input$approach)`, using `filter(Sx_Approach %in% input$approach)` seems to have worked too.  I shall give your answer a try though. Much appreciated